# Loading multiple JSON records into BigQuery using the console

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I'm trying to upload some data into bigquery in JSON format using the BigQuery Console as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local).

If I have a single record in a JSON file I can upload it successfully. If I put two or more records in a JSON file with newline delimination then I get this error:

```
 Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Parser terminated before end of string
```

I tried searching stackoverflow and google but didn't have any luck finding any information. The two records I uploaded with newline delimination are able to upload successfully as individual records in separate JSON files.

Answer (score 1):

My editor must have been adding some other character on my newlines. I went back to my original json array of records and used:

```
cat test.json | jq -c '.[]' > testNDJSON.json
```

This fixed everything.